# Why does this Kotlin code have a type mismatch?

Tags: kotlin

Your task is to implement the indexOfMax() function so that it returns
the index of the largest element in the array, or null if the array is empty.

```
package maxindex

import kotlin.collections.*

fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? {
    if (a.isNotEmpty()) {
        var maxValue = a.max()
        return a.indexOf(maxValue) // Type mismatch
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check the specific error message you get, it says: `required: Int, found: Int?` so you need a non-null int there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.max()` returns `null` if and only if `a` is empty. So inside `if (a.isNotEmpty())` it'll never be null, and `a.indexOf(maxValue)` takes a non-null `Int`.

So this code would be fine, but Kotlin's type system can't express "`a.max()` never returns `null` if `a` is not empty" and doesn't track array emptiness in the same way it tracks nullability. So you need to handle the `maxValue == null` case even though it can't actually happen.

Answer (score 2):

I remember when I first started out with Kotlin and I was confused when it said things like "this variable is mutable so safe-casting is not allowed" and I had no idea what was going on :)

Anyways, you're getting a type mismatch because the language has typed nullability. So you cannot *potentially* give `null` to `indexOf` because it demands it to be a non-null `Int`.

If you check the source code for `max()`:

```
public fun IntArray.max(): Int? {
    if (isEmpty()) return null
    ....
```

So it **can** give you `null`, and therefore you get

```
val maxValue: Int? = a.max()
```

Where you cannot supply `maxValue` as an argument for `indexOf`, because it expects `Int`, and not `Int?`.

So the solution is to handle the `null` case explicitly:

```
return maxValue?.let { a.indexOf(it) } ?: null
```

But now, based on what we know you could greatly reduce the lines of code like this:

```
fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? = a.max()?.let { a.indexOf(it) }
```

Which you'll later be able to turn into an extension function:

```
fun IntArray.indexOfMax(): Int? = max()?.let { indexOf(it) }
```

---

Good luck with your journey through Kotlin. Personally I think the Koans are very irritating, I preferred converting Java code to Kotlin to see what it's like to learn the initial syntactic quirks.

Comment: I've just checked and it's because we have to use `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf` for some reason

Comment: My code in the end was: `fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? = a.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let { a -> a.lastIndexOf(a.max()!!) }`  (although using run instead of let might make more sense here)

Comment: fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int?{
   if (a.isEmpty()){
       return null
   }else{
       return a.lastIndexOf(a.max()!!)
   }   
}

Comment: I actually didn't do a whole course or anything, I mostly learned from 1.) converting an existing big project and figuring out strange quirks that I documented [in this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/odd-things-to-look-out-for-when-converting-code-to-kotlin-a00b6239828c), and 2.) I watched this video: https://academy.realm.io/posts/kau-jake-wharton-testing-robots/ and 3.) I'm working on a full-Kotlin project with two other devs and they know a bunch of tricks :D it took me a while to understand `let`/`run`/`apply`/`also`/`takeif`/`takeUnless` but it chains quite nicely once you get it :D

Comment: And what's cool is that you can [check out the source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/9ffd0db4a87116a0c825f2f0163b8ad3eb1a922f/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L45-L49) for some of these tricky things. It helps! Although I advise watching that video I linked, first.